# Log to memory then write to file, memory stream vs file compared

Tags: c#, performance, file-io, io, stream

this is in references to my previous question [Log to memory and then write to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867875/log-to-memory-and-then-write-to-file/10867962), actually the edit part of that question, I asked in edit part that if I write to memory would that be faster than writing to file? I performed a simple test, and I had shocking results! I wanted to share with the community.
So here's the code

```
private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\File1.txt", string.Format("{0}Start! : {1}", Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
        {
             File.AppendAllText(@"D:\File1.txt", string.Format("{0}{1}:{2}", Environment.NewLine, i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), j.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
         }
    }
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\File1.txt", string.Format("{0}Done!{1}", Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    stopwatch.Stop();
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\File1.txt",
                       string.Format("{0}{1}:{2}",Environment.NewLine,              stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(), stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}

private void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
     using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
     {
         using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(mem))
         {
             stopwatch.Start();
             {
                 binaryWriter.Write("start! : " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                 {
                     for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
                     {
                         binaryWriter.Write(i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ":" + j.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                     }
                 }
                 stopwatch.Stop();
                 binaryWriter.Write("Done! " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                 binaryWriter.Write(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString() + ":" + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                 binaryWriter.Flush();
                 var file = new FileStream(@"D:\File2.txt", FileMode.Create);
                 mem.WriteTo(file);
             }
         }
     }
     MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
```

As the code should be easy to understand

[image: Performance Comparison]

```
Elapsed time in File1.txt = 00:50:24.5654918  
Elapsed milliseconds in File1.txt = 3024565  
Elapsed time in File2.txt = 00:00:04.7430152  
Elapsed milliseconds in File2.txt = 4743
```

**So, as you can see for yourself, there is about 50 minutes of differences!** This could be a real cause for bad perfromance, if you log everything directly to IO File, without use of memory stream or any custom tool for logging, OTOH ***compared to 50 minutes of File.AppendAllText, using MemoryStream only took about  4 and a quarter second***. (*I am still confused as to why the time shown in windows explorer doesn't corresponds to time shown in file in the end by stopwatch.ShowElapasedTime, but nonetheless, even if we see windows explorer time, its still about 45 minutes faster!*) So, this can be a really useful thing, I thought of sharing it!

Comment: Not very shocking. Just a result of doing IO wrong.

Comment: @harold
what is wrong in here?

Comment: IO works in blocks, with streams on top of them to make it more manageable. One of the results is that writing a a tiny block takes about as much time as writing a large block. Using a stream, all the short writes can be concatenated and written in a large block. Using `AppendAllText`, it just has to write out whatever you gave it right now, because there is no guarantee that you will ever call it again. You already have stream code in place, also use that for the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because File.AppendAllText opens the file, writes, flushes the buffer and closes it. If you keep the log file open and use a stream to write to it (instead of the MemoryStream), you will get results that are very close to what you've seen with MemoryStream - it might even be indistinguishable.

Try it out.

Comment: Actually writing directly to disk can become quite a bit faster for large amounts of data, since it doesn't need to reallocate giant arrays in memory (which also tends to cause out of memory exceptions).

Comment: It will almost certainly be faster writing directly to the file if you specify a larger buffer (up to about 64K) when you open the file. Alternatively, you can use a `BufferedStream` attached to the output stream.